# What happens exactly when you assign mload(0x40) to an address variable?

Tags: solidity

Size of an address is 20 bytes, which is smaller than the size of a slot. I didn't find any reference for what exactly happens in this case:

```
address tempBytes;
   assembly {
     tempBytes := mload(0x40) // 0x40 is the free memory pointer
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The free memory pointer holds the position of the first unallocated memory position. Assuming there are no in-memory variables before this snippet, the first free memory slot is at position 0x80 (decimal 128, beginning of the 5th 32byte slot).

Meaning `mload(0x40)` (reads the value of the pointer located at `0x40`) returns `0x80` (the value of the pointer).

Docs: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.16/internals/layout_in_memory.html

When a smaller type is casted to a larger type, it is prepended with leading zeros.

---

Applied to your example:

1. `mload(0x40)` returns `0x80`
2. this value is typecased to `address`
3. the value of `address tempBytes` is `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000080` (20 bytes, ends with hex`80`)

Comment: So here truncating happens when variable size < slot size; What about when variable size > slot size?

Comment: @mathematicanewbie Memory slot has always 32 bytes, and there is no scalar type larger than 32 bytes... However, if you were to typecast from a larger to a smaller variable type (e.g. `uint16` to `uint8`), it truncates the leading positions. Example: `uint16` value `258` (binary `00000001 00000010`) typecasted to `uint8` becomes `2` (binary `00000010`).

Comment: if `tempBytes` is of type `bytes`, then it's larger than a slot. The first slot contains length. Consider `tempBytes := mload(0x40)` in this case.

Comment: @mathematicanewbie Same goes for dynamic-size arrays. If the array is 41 bytes, and you're typecasting it to a 40byte type, the highest byte is omitted.

Comment: I think the behavior is very different from assigning to address variable. For bytes,`tempBytes := mload(0x40)` is allocating `tempBytes` at the position returned by `mload(0x40)`. Or do I miss something here?

Comment: @mathematicanewbie I meant 20byte type (40 hex chars, an `address` type), my mistake. Scalar types are <= 32 bytes, which is the slot size. Array and struct values can span across multiple slots... Your snippet is not allocating `tempBytes` at the position. It is assigning whichever value is stored at `0x40` to the `tempBytes` variable.

Comment: @mathematicanewbie It does not make much of a difference if `tempBytes` is of `bytes` or `address` type. Again, it assigns whatever value is stored at `0x40` to the `tempBytes` variable. If the value is larger than the size of the type of `tempBytes`, it is truncated to fit the `tempBytes` size.

Comment: I think we have different opinions here, I think for `bytes` variable, it's allocating `tempBytes` at the position `mload(0x40)`, that's the whole point of free memory pointer IMO.Otherwise you can't make sense of this line of code:https://github.com/polynetwork/eth-contracts/blob/1011bf8ab21c620129190b229cca268ebbdc2b94/contracts/libs/utils/Utils.sol#L244

Comment: @mathematicanewbie The linked snippet assigns the free memory pointer value to `tempBytes` (line 242), increases it by 0x20 (line 244, `add()` function) and then stores the updated value as the new value of the free memory pointer (line 244, `mstore()` function). However it does not perform any typecasting or truncating so I got a little lost about relevancy to your original question.

Comment: What happens when assigning the free memory pointer value to tempBytes of bytes type? I think `tempBytes` is allocated where free memory pointer value points to, otherwise there's no need to increase this pointer by 0x20 (size of a slot). Isn't the behavior different from the address type case?